# How to keep the speech recognition in python running indefinitely?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

*I am making an AI assistant using python . For that I need a speech-to-text service which keeps on listening , and starts working when it catches a certain keyword*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use The Speech_Recognition Module Of Python And Add It to While True() Loop.. Like -

```py
while True():
    #The Speech Recognition Code - 
    if recognized_text == "Bananas":
        #do stuff
```

The Tutorial For This Can Be Found On Google Easily.. Just Search **How To Make Speech Recognition In Python** or Follow This Link - 
[Youtube Tutorial 1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwikrsbYyefpAhUn4zgGHQuYBCwQwqsBMAJ6BAgLEAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DK_WbsFrPUCk&usg=AOvVaw3BcD9PesIqMrJ8t72mx0Hk)

And If You Are Making An AI Assistant, Why Aren't You Using Tensorflow And TFLEARN And Training It Into An Actual AI Assistant like SIRI or Google Assistant... You Are Just Making An IF AND ELSE Statement, You Cant Write All Possible Inputs Of Normal Human... I Suggest You Follow ***Tech With Tim*** Series Of Making A  Chatbot and then you can link The Speech Recognition Module With This Chatbot.. So, It Will Be A Perfect AI Assistant...

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer :) . Your Idea of using tensorflow may be good , but I am a newbie to python and I have no idea about AI or ML . And there is so much of material on the internet that I am confused what to start with . It would be really cool if you would just tell me where to start with !